# How to fail if previous command found invalid files in gitlab script?

Tags: json, linux, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a gitlab.yml script which I am running as below:

```
script:
  - ls -lrth
  - find Data/ -name "*.json" -print0 | while IFS= read -d '' -r filename; do
        if ! jq . "$filename" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
            echo "$filename bad";
        fi
    done
  - # how can I check if above find command found invalid json files and if it did then fail and doesn't move to next command
  - # some other unix commands here
```

My `find` command finds all the json files which are invalid. Now I want to fail my gitlab script if my `find` command finds invalid json files. Meaning it should print all invalid json files (which it is already doing) and then it should not go to the next command to execute.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Just `exit 1` after `echo`, no?

Comment: I want to print all invalid JSON files and then exit out of it if it found any invalid JSON files but not in the middle of it.

Comment: Then set some variable and exit later? `find ... | { failure=0; while ....... echo bad; failure=1; ....... done; exit "$failure"; }`. Also does the code work? Don't you get syntax error about the missing `;` after `echo` and after `fi`?

Comment: ohh we can do like that here? I wasn't aware of it. yeah that was copy paste mistake. will fix it. And yes it does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
  - find Data/ -name "*.json" -print0 | {
        status=0;
        while IFS= read -d '' -r filename; do
            if ! jq . "$filename" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
               echo "$filename bad";
               status=1;
            fi;
        done;
        exit "$status";
    }
```